# Mathematicians who are famous for reasons other than mathematics

Tags: soft-question, math-history, big-list

Charles L. Dodgson, better known as his pseudonym [Lewis Carroll](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lewis_Carroll), was a very skilled mathematician. However, that is probably not what he is most known for. Indeed, his story of [*Alice in Wonderland*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alice%27s_Adventures_in_Wonderland) is famous worldwide.

[image: Lewis Carroll, the author of Alice in Wonderland.]

> What are some good examples of mathematicians who have become well known for things not related to mathematics/science?

Comment: I think that this is an interesting question, and I am interested in the answers, but I don't think that it is about mathematics.  It would likely be better suited to the [History of Science and Math SE](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ted_Kaczynski

Comment: @XanderHenderson Ah, darn. Didn't think of that SE. If the community decides, can they move it?

Comment: It is definitely better here, more people come here than the other website.

Comment: [Hermann Grassmann](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermann_Grassmann) comes to mind. His Sanskrit dictionary and translation of the Rigveda are still standard references.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Danica_McKellar

Comment: @YoloInver The fact that more people come here is neither here-nor-there with respect to whether or not the question belongs here.

Comment: @Eff Only a $\diamondsuit$-moderator can move the question.  But you could, if you wanted, ask is on HSMSE (and, perhaps, delete this question).

Comment: no coment on this being on topic, but I'll make one tangentially off topic comment: having 3 or 4 foruns for just about the same subject is silly. 2 foruns for mathematics (one basic, one advanced), one for history, one for history of science - all are a fit for "history of math". Could someone get a clear cut criteria to tell what goes where? Or this will be quite detrimental. (probably this is best at some meta discussion, point me there if so, please)

Comment: [Pat Billingsley](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patrick_Billingsley)

Answer (score 21):

Here's my favorite:

[image]

Theodore John Kaczynski

Comment: Lol, so weird. :D

Comment: It feels weird to vote the unabomber.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Any more time on this site and we'll all end up like that guy.

Answer (score 10):

Here are some people who studied mathematics, but are more well known for other things:

**Ralph Abernathy** ~ civil rights leader and close associate of Martin Luther King, Jr., was a mathematics professor at Alabama State University

**Corazon Aquino** ~ former president of the Philippines, was a mathematics major at the College of Mt. St. Vincent

**Tammy Baldwin** ~ US Representative and US Senator from Wisconsin majored in polical science and mathematics at Smith College

**Harry Blackmun** ~ former Associate Justice of the US Supreme court (author of Roe v. Wade), graduated summa cum laude in mathematics from Harvard University

**Ahmed Chalabi** ~ controversial Iraqi Deputy Prime Minister, has a PhD in mathematics from the University of Chicago

**Lewis Carroll** (AKA Charles Dodgson) ~ author of Alice’s Adventures in Wonderland and Through the Looking-Glass, was a mathematician and logician who taught at Christ Church College Oxford. He was the author of a number of books on mathematics.

**David Dinkins** ~ former mayor of New York City, graduated magna cum laude with a BA in mathematics from Howard University

**Richard Garfield** ~ the game designer who created Magic: The Gathering received a PhD in math from the University of Pennsylvania where he studied under Herbert Wilf

**Art Garfunkel** ~ Paul Simon’s long-time collaborator, has a masters degree in mathematics from Columbia University (he left the PhD program to pursue his musical career)

**Philip Glass** ~ American composer, studied mathematics and philosophy at the University of Chicago

**Teri Hatcher** ~ actress, studied mathematics and engineering at De Anza College

**Heloise (Poncé Cruse Evans)** ~ syndicated columnist (Hints from Heloise) had a double major in business administration and mathematics, with a teacher’s certificate from Southwest Texas State University

**Michael Jordan** ~ basketball superstar, majored in mathematics until his junior year

**Theodore Kaczynski** ~ the unabomber, his PhD thesis in mathematics from the University of Michigan won the Sumner B. Myers Prize for best dissertation of the year

**Tom Lehrer** ~ Singer-songwriter and satirist, received a BA in mathematics (magna cum laude) from Harvard at the age of 18, he went on to complete an MA in mathematics and to start the PhD program

**Danica McKellar** ~ actress best known for playing Winnie Cooper on The Wonder Years, graduated summa cum laude in mathematics from UCLA. She is the author of the best-selling books Math Doesn’t Suck, and Kiss My Math

**Harriet Miers** ~ President G. W. Bush’s (unsuccessful) nominee to the US Supreme Court, has a bachelors degree in mathematics from Southern Methodist University

**Larry Niven** ~ award-winning science fiction author, received a bachelor’s degree in mathematics from Washburn University

**William J. Perry** ~ Secretary of Defense under Bill Clinton, received a PhD in mathematics from Penn State University (and a BA and MA from Stanford University, with George Pólya as his thesis advisor)

**David Robinson** ~ famous basketball player, nicknamed “The Admiral,” has a BS in mathematics from US Naval Academy

**Frank Ryan** ~ quarterback who led the Cleveland Browns to the 1964 NFL title, had a PhD in mathematics from Rice University

**Aleksandr Solzhenitsyn** ~ Nobel Prize-wining author of The Gulag Archipelago, had a degree in mathematics and physics from the University of Rostov

**Bram Stoker** ~ author of Dracula, received honors in mathematics from Trinity college, Dublin

**John Urshel** ~ this NFL player received a BS and MS in math from Penn State, and he is currently in a math PhD program at MIT

**Virginia Wade** ~ British tennis star, studied mathematics and physics and the University of Sussex

**Paul Wolfowitz** ~ U.S. Deputy Secretary of Defense and President of the World Bank, studied mathematics and chemistry at Cornell University

Comment: Did Michael Jordan really major in math?

Comment: @Michael Yup yup! :D https://www.math.uh.edu/~tomforde/famous.html

Comment: Thanks!  It looks like you cut-and-pasted your answer from that link.  Assuming you are not Tomforde, and to avoid plagiarism, I would mention at the start that you are pulling from that link...or just give the link.

Comment: @Michael I did not copy and paste just from one page. Can you find **Paul Wolforwitz** from that page?! How about **Aleksandr Solzhenitsyn** and **John Urshel**? There were 6 sources and one of them was Tomforde's page. And would be nicer if you first asked if I did so and I would answer like now. Anyway, thanks for your feedback and you are always welcome to comment. Thank you.

Comment: In that case, you may want to cite the other sources as well.  I originally assumed you had written all those short blurbs for each person.

Answer (score 8):

[Jim Simons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_Harris_Simons?wprov=sfti1) founded the hedge fund [Renaissance Technologies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Renaissance_Technologies?wprov=sfti1). He is also known for his work on [Chern-Simons forms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chern%E2%80%93Simons_form?wprov=sfti1).

[image: Simons]

Answer (score 3):

[André Bloch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andr%C3%A9_Bloch_(mathematician)) was a french soldier in WWI who, after he leaves the military service, killed some familiars. He was enclosed in an asylum.

After he was enclosed he did several contributions in the area of complex analysis. He was written his letters from the asylum and the mathematicians that read them doesnt knew he was confined.

Comment: This is **NOT** the portrait of André Bloch. It's another famous Bloch who was a Nobel prize winner: [Felix](https://www.gettyimages.fr/detail/photo-d'actualit%C3%A9/stanford-ca-dr-felix-bloch-stanford-university-photo-dactualit%C3%A9/515257548). As far as I know, there is no picture of him anywhere on the internet. And btw, I think the mistake is originated [from here](https://mathshistory.st-andrews.ac.uk/Biographies/Bloch).

Answer (score 1):

**[Daniel Biss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daniel_Biss)**-Was Assistant Professor at the University of Chicago. As of February 22, 2018, they are a member of the Illinois Senate and a candidate in the Democratic primary for Governor of Illinois.

**Ira Gessel**-In the 70's, they founded the [Committee to End Pay Toilets in America](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Committee_to_End_Pay_Toilets_in_America).

Answer (score 0):

[Masi Oka](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Masi_Oka) graduated from Brown University in mathematics and computer sciende, but is better known for his work as an actor (most notably for his role as Hiro Nakamura in NBS's *Heroes*).

[Dara Ó Briain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dara_%C3%93_Briain) studied theoretical physics and mathematics in University College Dublin, but he's known for his work as a stand-up comedian and panel show presenter (occasionally he has used his knowledge of mathematics in some shows).